# In SQL, is it possible update a column except some values?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have this scenario:

table 'x' column 'y'

and I want to update only some value of column 'y'.

For example: if 'y' >= 1000  "DON'T UPDATE ONLY THIS VALUE"

The question is: Is it possible update a column except some values?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Can you please give more details?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible to update only a column in selected rows.
That is why we have the where clause. In the where clause you specify the condition to find those selected rows.

```
update mytable
set x=NewValue
where y >= 1000 --or any other conditions or adjust your condition
```

Comment: I think it should be y<1000 looking at question

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE x set y=newVal WHERE y>=1000;
```

Comment: I think he wants UPDATE x set y=newVal WHERE y **<** 1000;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to only update certain rows in a table using a WHERE clause.

Now, in table **W**, if you want to update column *X* when column *Z* has a certain value and column *Y* when *Z* has a different value, you need to have two UPDATE statements with two different WHERE clauses. i.e.:

```
UPDATE W set X=1 WHERE Z=2
UPDATE W set Y=3 WHERE Z=5
```

SQL queries usually don't have embedded if-then logic (which is what you seem to be asking for).

Comment: `UPDATE W set X=(CASE WHEN Z=2 THEN 1 ELSE X END), Y=(CASE WHEN Z=5 THEN 3 ELSE Y END)`  For this example, the `CASE` statement embedded if-then logic doesn't gain anything, but in other situations it can be quite useful.